# How does iOS handle ics files?

Tags: ios, ical

I have a server running that simply returns ics file on a get request. I emailed the link to myself, and clicked on this link in the apple mail. Apple Mail redirects me to safari, request to the ics service is made, and I'm promoted to add the event. However, clicking on that link in the apple mail second time, redirects me to safari but nothing happens. Also, if I open this link directly from iOS Safari it works every time without any problems. Any idea why this could be happening only from apple mail?